# How can i change the "username" title field in wordpress registration

Tags: wordpress, field, registration, code-snippets

How can i change the wordpress registration "Username" [Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n8C2K.jpg)

Iv change the field on login page with this snippet :

```
add_filter( 'gettext', 'register_text' );
add_filter( 'ngettext', 'register_text' );
function register_text( $translated ) {
    $translated = str_ireplace(
        'Username or Email Address',
        'Business Email Address',
        $translated
    );
    return $translated;
}
```

But i have problem to change it on registration page like on the screen above. Can you please help me to provide correct snippet for this part please.